# How does mercurial compress files in repository?

Tags: mercurial

I'm seeing that mercurial efficiently compresses the files in repository

```
(repo/.hg/store/data)
```

Does anybody know what kind of compression is used for repository files?

Thanks.

Comment: Once data is compressed reasonably efficiently, trying to compress it again will usually result in slightly bigger file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two levels of compression in Mercurial repositories: delta storage, and [zlib compression](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/94114ea3503d/mercurial/revlog.py).

In addition, various other parts employ also compression. For example, bundles can be compressed with both gzip and bzip2, as can archive tarballs - but I don't think you were asking for these.

Comment: May want to note that Mercurial is in the process of changing the default compression to Zstandard which is giving significant improvements in performance and compression ratios. Mercurial 4.1 uses zstd for transmission if both client and server support it, but the repository format hasn't changed to it yet. <https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Release4.1> <http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Deltas-compression-and-zstd-td4046764.html?

Answer (score 5):

You might find Mercurial author [Matt Mackall's paper](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Presentations?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=ols-mercurial-paper.pdf) on the revlog format interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Initial versions of files are compressed using deflate (same algorithm as zip), but for updated files, Mercurial stores only a (binary) diff against a previous version.

It also tries to do the right thing: When a deflated JPEG turns out bigger than the original, it will not store it "compressed", for example.

Comment: It actually does a little more than that.  If you *only* store deltas, the time to regenerate a stored file from the revlogs grows as a function of the number of changesets (i.e. this an O(N) algorithm).  To bound that process Mercurial periodically stores the entire file *again*, and relies on the zlib compression to squash that back down to a reasonable size.