# List SIZE of mercurial changesets?

Tags: mercurial, changeset

Looking to quantify how much change happened in each changeset.  Any quick way to list maybe kb diff between two revisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hg log --stat` is the command you're after. See this example:

```
$ hg log --stat

changeset:   12431:56e146c7beef
user:        flast
date:        Wed Jun 08 16:12:54 2011 +1000
summary:     Fix the frobulate to frob the knob correctly on tuesdays.

 path/to/src/frob/interface.py       |  29 ++++++++++++++++++++---------
 path/to/tests/systest_frob.py       |  14 ++++++++++++++
 2 files changed, 34 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same thought as @shambulator yesterday! So I've added ability to print [delta size in bytes](https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch/commit/0ff4532aab977478451ebd3f63c1d7b899e2e26f) as a part of `--diffstat` output from my [somewhat long and clean patch.py](https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch/blob/master/patch.py) utility.

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/techtonik/python-patch/master/patch.py
hg diff -c tip | python patch.py --diffstat --
 codereview/views.py | 28 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 index.yaml          | 10 ++++++++++
 2 files changed, 38 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-), +1267 bytes
```

**UPD**: Thanks to @Gili and @mforbes there is now a ticket for Mercurial
  https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4245

Comment: Thanks for the script! I filed a ticket: http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4245

Comment: That may help. Thanks.

Comment: The bug server is now at https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4245

Comment: The source has moved to GitHub: https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch/blob/master/patch.py

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps one can use [`hg bundle`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/bundle) to check the size?  *(I have not checked how consistent this is in terms of the total repository size.)*

```
function revsize() {
  hg bundle -r $1 --base "p1($1)+p2($1)" /dev/stdout | wc -c
}
```

**How it works**

This computes the size (in bytes) using [`wc -c`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc) after generating a bundle for the changes between revision `REV = $1` (the first argument to the bash function) and [its parents](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/parents) `"p1(REV)+p2(REV)"` (there may be two if it is a merge.) By using `/dev/stdout` as a file, the result is sent to standard out where it can be piped to `wc -c` without creating a file on disk.

Comment: Note that by default, bundles are compressed using bzip2. For no compression, use "-t none" (see hg bundle docs linked above).

Comment: @Kim Do you know if the differences are stored compressed on disk or not?  If not, ``-t none`` is probably best, but this all needs some testing (or an authoritative source.)

Comment: According to this ancient [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1270485/3387608), initial files are compressed, but diffs are uncompressed. I haven't verified this independently or found a more recent confirmation though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thought only yesterday! I wrote [a quick and dirty Python script](http://pastebin.com/JdrdaiZy) for determining total file size change given a unified diff on stdin or as files on the command line. To do it for a changeset, you could just:

```
hg diff -c <cset id> | patchsize.py
```

Quick and dirty in the sense that it probably doesn't account for platform-specific line endings, and it doesn't parse diffs particularly cleverly. But it's close enough for my purposes.

Comment: Yep, I use it all the time. But it only goes as far as line insertions and deletions; I was curious about the total change in file sizes introduced by a patch.